# Separate directories for git repos

Tags: git, github, development-environment

I am somewhat new to git and even though I would have thought my question should be pretty common, I can't find an answer to it.

I am currently contributing to 2 git repositories. Locally, I have them both cloned in the same directory. However, I would like to move one of them to a different local directory. I know how to change the default directory but that's not what I want because then both repos would just be checked out into that "new" default directory. I just want two separate directories into which I can clone the two repos separately. Anyone know how to do that?

Current dir structure:

```
Development
|
|-- HTML
    |
    |-- Git Default Dir
        |
        |-- Project 1
        |
        |-- Project 2
```

Desired dir structure:

```
Development
|
|-- HTML
    |
    |-- Git Dir Project 1
    |
    |-- Git Dir Project 2
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Backup everything (just in case)
2) Delete Development directory
3) Create Development directory
4) Go to Development directory and create 2 new directories "Project1" and "Project2"
5) Go to Project1 and clone the repo you want in that directory

```
git clone git@domain.com/repo.git .
```

Note: Notice the "."

6) Go to Project2 directory and do step 5 using the proper url

Comment: Thank you, that pretty much did it. However, I got an error with the additional "." so I simply left it out. What was it meant to accomplish?

Comment: the "." is to tell git to put all the checked out files in the current directory you are in.